# Is there a closed-form solution for this problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ be a full column rank matrix. Then there exists a left inverse $A^+$ of $A$. Let $w\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector. Is there a closed-form solution for the following problem?

$$
\begin{aligned}
\min\limits_{A^+} \ & \|{A^+}^Tw\|_1\\
\text{s.t.} \ & A^+A= I
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is an explicit solution, but you can translate this problem into a linear program.

You can parameterize $A^+$ by means of the cokernel of $A$. Let
$$
A^+ = (A^TA)^{-1}A^T + XB
$$
where $X$ is an $n\times (m-n)$ matrix and $B$ is an $(m-n) \times m$ that contains a basis of the cokernel of $A$ as its rows. Let $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and
$$
y= ((A^TA)^{-1}A^T + XB)^Tw
$$
Introduce $z\in\mathbb{R}^m.$ Then the linear program is
$$
\min \sum_{i=1}^m z_i
$$
such that
\begin{eqnarray}
y - B^TX^Tw & = & A(A^TA)^{-1}w \\
y_i & \leq & z_i \\
-y_i & \leq & z_i
\end{eqnarray}
(The variables are $X$, $y$ and $z$)

Comment: I'm well aware that this can be efficiently solved. I'm interested in a closed-form because in the problem I'm working on, $w$ would be a decision variable along with $A^+$